# Postgresql Multiple Left Joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I am trying to get a list from a table and have joins made on two columns.I think it would be better if I show you what I am trying to do and hopefuly it will make sense.

**Users table:**

```
username |  emailaddress  |                            socialkey                             |                                                       avatarpic                                
----------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bobert   | bob@none.com   | 9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a | https://craftedin.co/static/images/user/avatars/thumbs/59159be40a8c76.26091804.jpg
 Mikey    | mike@none.com  | 3bcd6c5f811ba06aa49c2df9504fe5416f35702b78bcdc15ecbd5137fabdca59 | http://cdn1-www.cattime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/siamese-cats-and-kittens-pictures/siamese-ca
 Mary     | mary@none.com  | f96197d19984b6f4a457ff0aed1c5bd222ffc2db51f30e4e8170ae02cb007ded | http://foopic.com
 Katya    | katya@none.com | 11ba72d57246c08ccbb9e201fb242a3f578d698e7d787d4a1aa08c8897b6cd80 | http://foopic.com
```

**Friends table:**

```
    usera     |     userb      
---------------+----------------
 mike@none.com | bob@none.com
 mary@none.com | bob@none.com
 bob@none.com  | katya@none.com
```

My query takes the users **socialkey** and makes a lookup. Unfortunately, this is giving me bad results. I want to use the users **socialkey**

```
with Sfriends as (
   select * 
   from friends 
   where usera = (select emailaddress 
                  from users 
                  where socialkey = '9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a')) 
     or (userb = (select emailaddress 
                  from users 
                  where socialkey = ('9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a')))
), socialkeys as (
  select socialkey,username,emailaddress,avatarpic 
  from users
) 
select Sfriends.usera, socialkey , avatarpic, Sfriends.userb,socialkey 
from Sfriends as foo 
   left join Socialkeys on foo.usera = socialkeys.emailaddress 
   left join Sfriends on foo.userb = socialkeys.emailaddress;
```

**Here is what I want:**

```
user-namea |     usera     |                          userasocialkey                          | usera-avatar-pic | user-nameb |     userb      |                          userbsocialkey                          |     userb-avatar-pic     
----------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------
 Mikey    | mike@none.com | 3bcd6c5f811ba06aa49c2df9504fe5416f35702b78bcdc15ecbd5137fabdca59 | usera-avatar-pic | Bobert    | bob@none.com   | 9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a | userb-avatar-pic
 Mary     | mary@none.com | f96197d19984b6f4a457ff0aed1c5bd222ffc2db51f30e4e8170ae02cb007ded | usera-avatar-pic | bobert    | bob@none.com   | 9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a | userb-avatar-pic
 Bobert   | bob@none.com  | 9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a | usera-avatar-pic | Katya     | katya@none.com | 11ba72d57246c08ccbb9e201fb242a3f578d698e7d787d4a1aa08c8897b6cd80 | userb-avatar-pic
```

I am willing to have the socialkey inserted into the friends table if that will help things.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the CTE `socialkeys` is useless. You can directly join to the `users` table in the final select

Comment: I'm finding it hard to follow, is your question "for every user in Users, join their friends"?. Is their duplicated data in friends? Meaning A B and B A?

Comment: for every usera , userb in friends join users.socialkey and avatarpic. So I need usera and userb to be shown with his socialkey and his coresponding pic

Comment: If every pair of friends in Friends can appear twice like mike@none.com | bob@none.com and bob@none.com | mike@none.com then surely you can do a simple join from Users email address to Friends' User B, then Select Friends User A and Users' username column. Doing so lists all usernames, and their associated friend, retaining the social key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to join `users` twice, once for `usera` and once for `userb` from `friends`.

```
SELECT ua.username,
       ua.emailaddress,
       ua.socialkey,
       ua.avatarpic,
       ub.username,
       ub.emailaddress,
       ub.socialkey,
       ub.avatarpic
       FROM friends f
            INNER JOIN users ua
                       ON ua.emailaddress = f.usera
            INNER JOIN users ub
                       ON ub.emailaddress = f.userb
       WHERE '9784e946c53d44c975ee91625486d758fe630f176d44863080ec689ae3cd536a' IN (ua.socialkey,
                                                                                    ub.socialkey);
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was trying to do earlier, but with joining it as Sfriends.  The problem I ran into was the error of referencing Sfriends twice and I was sure that I shouldn't need to make two CTEs for the same thing. Anyway this works! Thanks!